# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found everything seems fine and still getting this error

Tags: django

this is my str and unicode...

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.id

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title or u''
```

and i have already tried this...

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.id

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

still getting this error..

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

[not able to figure it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJyFq.png)

Comment: Did the below answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already got the answer.....but thnx for ur rply

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to implement both methods. If you're using `python 2` then use `__unicode__`. If you're using `python 3` use `__str__`.

So, using python 2 do this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.id)
```

For python 3 do this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.id)
```